# Eigen3/C++: Tile a MatrixXd with a Vector3d

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen3

What is the most elegant way in 'Eigen3/C++' to construct a `MatrixXd` 
from a repeated `Vector3d`. That is, given a row vector

```
     Eigen::Vector3d  V(v00, v01, v02);
```

the goal is to find an operation `op` such that

```
     Eigen::MatrixXd  M = op(V, N);
```

delivers a matrix `M` consisting of `N` rows which are equal to `V`, i.e.

```
    /  v00  v01  v02  \
    |  v00  v01  v02  |
M = |      ...        |
    |                 | 
    \  v00  v01  v02  /
```

similar to what can be achieved by `tile` in `numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vectorwise and dense expressions can *replicate*:

```
V.rowwise().replicate(N).transpose() // or
V.transpose().colwise().replicate(N) // or
V.transpose().replicate(N,1) // or ...
```

of which there are also corresponding versions when N and/or the direction is known at compile time...